# Is it possible to deploy a Sharepoint Foundation content database to Azure SQL Services?

Tags: 2013, database, sql, content, azure

We are starting a new project and to be costly effective we need to use Sharepoint Foundation 2013.
We are planning to deploy both Sharepoint and Database to cloud. For Sharepoint we will use a virtual machine, and we are planning use the SQL Azure for content databases instead of a local database. Is that possible? Does anyone tried this before?

Comment: Any reason for not going the Office 365 way? To expensive compared to Foundation?

Comment: Its a public website, the customers have a little "Personal Area" that they can access some announcements and documents. So, if we go office 365 we will have large costs of licensing, and its a website for a small company. Besides this, they want to integrate the customers from an existing database, not recreating the users again. Did you see that possible on office 365?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a possibility to use SQL Azure for content databases. But you deploy SQL server on Virtual machine on Azure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn275959.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/umits/archive/2014/01/08/resources-and-guidelines-for-deploying-sharepoint-on-windows-azure-virtual-machines.aspx

Comment: I was looking through this possibility too. But now I left the idea of having a remote database for another problem: We need to have a domain to setup sharepoint with remote database. I would need a domain controller at Azure...? My point was just to have a backup if some problem occurs, I decided then to use regular sharepoint backups to a storage on Azure. If we lost the machine for any problem we can recover all the data from backups.